# Do I have to create SQL statement when using SQLite3 to build a database table with multiple columns and values use VS code SQLite extension?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am looking for an answer for my issue: I am working on a Python Tkinter file management desktop application for a company internship.
I am using VS code editor, the code you will see is from VS code extension SQLite database table.
I have inserted the first record successfully in the DB table, but not sure why the second record and third record does not display in the DB table.

I am not sure why I inserted the first record alright but the second one not quite work: below is my code. I have quite a large pre-loaded data from Excel Spreadsheet to transfer into the database, so I just testing two records first.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS papers (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  filename TEXT NOT NULL,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  keywords TEXT NOT NULL,
  author TEXT NOT NULL,
  year INTEGER NOT NULL,
  filepath TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO papers (id, filename, title, keywords, author, year, filepath) 
VALUES ("full01_Munandar_Geothermal resources development in Indonesia", 
"Geothermal resources development in Indonesia", "geothermal; Indonesia; vocanic; non-vocanic", "A. Munandar; S. Widodo", 2013, 
"\\well-srv04\data\Technical Resources\Papers, books and publications - External to Quest\Conferences\AGS 2013\2013Paper\full01_Munandar_Geothermal resources development in Indonesia.pdf
"),

("full04_TaeJongLee_YR 2013 country update on geothermal energy in Korea", 
"Yr 2013 Country Update on Geothermal Energy in Korea",
"geothermal heat pump (GHP); enhanced geothermal system (EGS); direct use; power generation; EGS potential; technological roadmap (TRM)", 
"T.J. Lee; Y. Song", 2013, 
"\\well-srv04\data\Technical Resources\Papers, books and publications - External to Quest\Conferences\AGS 2013\2013Paper\full04_TaeJongLee_YR 2013 country update on geothermal energy in Korea.pdf
");
```

I am not sure SQLite need to add "INSERT INTO papers (id, filename, title, keywords, author, year, filepath)
VALUES (......)" this statement repeating every time I add new value to the table?

The result show: one record added but not the second one.

Thanks

Comment: You're missing the values for the `id` column in your `VALUES` list. If you want it to auto-increment, either provide the value `NULL` in the `VALUES`, or leave the column out of the column list.

Comment: You're only getting one row because it's treating the filename as the ID. Since it's not a number, it's being converted to the value `0`. The second row gets an error because it's duplicating the primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have adjusted the code removed the ID in my column. And refreshed the DB. But I am still getting only one row..                                                        INSERT INTO papers (filename, title, keywords, author, year, filepath) 
VALUES ()

Comment: What if you do it with two separate `INSERT` queries instead of multiple lists of values?

Comment: Thanks for the response again. I removed the ID and refresh, add a new query it seems work :) But I need to remove some of the rows of records as it duplicates once I add the new records and it repeats to add the previous records. Is there a way to just delete the duplicate records to keep the DB table clean without any duplicate records?

Comment: Declare the column that shouldn't be repeated as `UNIQUE`. Then use `INSERT OR IGNORE` and it will skip the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks again, I am pretty new to this, so your information has been helpful for my early coding journey:)

Comment: Also, I found DB Browser for SQLite to build an extensive database says hundreds and thousand of rows of data and multiple tables would be a more user-friendly interface if not code-savvy yet.